# how to display picture from database to picture gallery?

Tags: database, imagebutton

I have a page gallery.aspx.

In the this page are 3 imagebuttons.

How do I connect my database to this image buttons for display images?

Comment: Further explanation and some context would be nice. Maybe even some example code.

Answer (score 0):

> var con = new SqlConnection(settings.ConnectionString);
>
> var cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Photo from Members where Member_No = " + ID, con);
>
> con.Open();
>
> Image img = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
>
> imageButton.image = img;